# absent border on dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

On the following I am not getting a border-left on the drop down menu. This might have something to do with left:0; but adjusting this does not make a difference. Also I'm trying to post this but it keeps asking for more details, is there some kind of word min?

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article,
aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer,
header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* setting below are not found in meyers */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

/*MASTER ONLY*/

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 400px;
  background: linen;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

/* Topmenu */

ul, li {
  float: right;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
ul.topmenu {
  height: 100px;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
}
li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: linen;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}
li a:hover {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
}

/* Submenu */

.topmenu li:hover ul {
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
ul.submenu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9000px;
  background: linen;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
ul.submenu li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul.submenu li a {
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul.submenu li a:hover {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, meant to write border-left on drop down menu.

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle in case someone wants it: https://jsfiddle.net/rf29hry5/

Comment: @Staveven that's unnecessary, there's a working code snippet. Nobody has to leave the site to demo the issue or produce a working solution.

Comment: @hungerstar Oh I see that code snippets can be run on Stack Overflow now. My mistake!

Comment: @Staveven no problem, just a heads up. There are times where a JSFiddle is a little more capable than a Code Snippet. In those cases, by all means, use JSFIddle. But for the simpler stuff I highly recommend Code Snippets so nobody is chasing down code and verifiable examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left border is disappearing because the `<a>` of `.submenu` are overlapping `.submenu`. Your CSS states that `.submenu` and the `<li>` of `.submenu` should be 200px in width. Your `<a>` are block level so they will match their parent `<li>`.

The issue arises from using `box-sizing: border-box;` (which is totally cool to use). When you use this property, the width will **include** padding and borders. So your `.submenu` is actually 190px wide with a 5px border on each side while the `<li>` of `.submenu` are 200px wide (and floated).

There's a number of fixes you could use.

One would be to remove the float on the `li` of `.submenu` and not set a universal width on `li`. Be more specific as to which `li` should be `width: 100px;` and be floated. In the future you might have some content on the page that will use an `li` for an ordered/unordered (bullet) list. You'll barely be able to get any text per line when `width: 100px;` is applied to it (you might not want it to be 60px in height either). I've done this by using the following selector: `.topmenu > li`.

`li` by default are block level and will fill their parent element, use that to your advantage.

***Note:***  A lot of your selectors could be scoped to the menu so they do not inadvertently affect future elements of the same kind, see above.

**Add:**

```
.topmenu > li {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**Remove:**
    ul, li {
      float: right;
    }
    li {
      width: 100px;
    }

**Change:**

```
ul.submenu li {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article,
aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer,
header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* setting below are not found in meyers */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

/*MASTER ONLY*/

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 400px;
  background: linen;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

/* Topmenu */

ul, li {
  float: right;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
ul.topmenu {
  height: 100px;
}
.topmenu > li {
  width: 100px;
}
li {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
}
li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: linen;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}
li a:hover {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
}

/* Submenu */

.topmenu li:hover ul {
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
ul.submenu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9000px;
  background: linen;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
ul.submenu li {
  float: none;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul.submenu li a {
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul.submenu li a:hover {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please also note that your menu items might not be in the same order as you expect them to be when using `float: right;`. When using `float: right;` they get reversed. Currently it's hard to see as they all have the same label.

Example:

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This results in the a with 100% width to overlap the border. I simply removed the border-box and tadaa!

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address,
big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article,
aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer,
header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* setting below are not found in meyers */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

/*MASTER ONLY*/

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 400px;
  background: linen;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

/* Topmenu */

ul, li {
  float: right;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
ul.topmenu {
  height: 100px;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
}
li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: linen;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}
li a:hover {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
}

/* Submenu */

.topmenu li:hover ul {
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
ul.submenu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9000px;
  background: linen;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
ul.submenu li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul.submenu li a {
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul.submenu li a:hover {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works, it might be more counter productive as removing `box-sizing: border-box` has wide reaching implications as it's applied to **everything**.

Comment: Just a quick idea: you can also add a border to the a element. That should solve it as well. The main thing here is that the background of the a is overlapping with the border. Easy enough to fix and plenty of ways to do it, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Very helpful. I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

The border-box code is causing the left border to remain hidden. You just need to remove this code from your CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a working JSFiddle without the border-box CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/rf29hry5/